# Apply transformations to make array sorted

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

We are given M numbers and each number has a list of values associated with it. We can change it with any of the number from the list (It will also be between 1 to M only).

So we are having (Its maximum size can be 200 X 200):

```
vector<vector<int>> transformations
```

Now we are having another array with N integers and we want to make it sorted in increasing order.

**NOTE : We can only change a number once.**

We need to tell the minimum numbers that are to be changed to make it sorted.In case its not possible then also we must return -1 as answer, else count of minimum alphabets to be changed.

Each number in this array can be changed exactly once. So I think there must be some dynamic programming that can help into this. N can be up to 200000. I thought of greedy solution, But that won't work for some cases.

Like say we have M=3 and vector of vector  transformations as follow :

```
1->{1,2}
2->{1,2}
3->{3,4}
4->{3,4}
```

Now if N=4 and array is [2,1,3,4] then answer is 2 as we can change 2->1 and 1->2

But if transformations are same , N=4 and array be [3,4,1,2] then answer is -1 as we can never make it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved using Dynamic Programming by following the next recursive formula:

- `i` is an index
- `x` is the value from the set that can populate each index (can be transformed to index based of these values easily)

```
 D(0)(x) = 1   | x is not the original value    //1 value array is sorted
 D(0)(x) = 0   | x is the original value
 D(i)(x) = min{D(i-1)(y) +1 | y < x} U { D(i-1)(y) | y<x, y is original value}  U {INFINITY}
```

The idea is to take the minimal possible value for each value of `i,x` among:

- `D(i-1)(y) +1 | y < x}` - any swap
- `{ D(i-1)(y) | y<x, y is original value}` - no swap is needed
- `{INFINITY}`  - no way to get a sorted array to this location

Python Code:

```
orig = [2,1,3,4] 
vals = [[1,2],[1,2],[3,4],[3,4]]
D = [[1,1]]
for x in range(len(vals[0])):
    if vals[0][x] == orig[0]:
        D[0][x] = 0
    else: 
        vals[0][x] = 1
for i in range(1,len(orig)):
    D.append([max_int32, max_int32])
print D
for i in range(1,len(orig)):
    for x in range(len(vals[i])):
        for y in range(len(vals[i-1])):
            if vals[i-1][y] < vals[i][x] and vals[i][x] != orig[i]:

                D[i][x] = min(D[i][x],D[i-1][y] + 1)
            elif vals[i-1][y] < vals[i][x]:
                D[i][x] = min(D[i][x],D[i-1][y])
print min(D[len(orig)-1])
```

For other arrays, need to modify `orig` and `vals` accordingly, for example for `[3,4,1,2]`:

```
orig = [3,4,1,2] 
vals = [[3,4],[3,4],[1,2],[1,2]]
```

Here, `max_int32`  indicates it cannot be done - you can easily swap it to `-1`.

Comment: Can you explain it with some example or so ? Am not able to get python, or a code in c++/ java would be great

Comment: Are you using 1 based indexing ?

Comment: @Mrinal Python is fairly simple and is almost like pseudo code. try to think of it as pseudo-code and you'll see you understand it. Think to notice: `range(x)` generates all values [0,1,...,x-1]`, `i in X` is for each loop, `len(X)` is the length of the array X (java's `X.length`)

Comment: And whats D = [[1,1]] ?

Comment: Also I guess complexity for this is O(NMM) if am not wrong ?

Comment: Right about complexity, given your constraints, it shouldn't be an issue (200^3 = 8,000,000). `D = [[1,1]]` is creating an array (called list in python) where the first element of it is the array [1,1]

Comment: You mean 2D array with 1 row and 1 column  ? And can complexity be reduced ?

Comment: Length of orig is 200000

Comment: 8,000,000,000 is still pretty fast for modern machines.

Comment: I had tried to convert it to C++ : http://ideone.com/a7iV5N  But getting wrong results. Please help in finding bug